# How to convert slash separated string to array of string

Tags: arrays, string

I have string as=
`var str = "9\10\16"` .
i want to convert it into array of strings as= `["9","10","16"]`. So how to get such output

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: i am using extjs [javascript]

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your language. Most of them have a method which directly splits the string to an array. Some examples:

Java:

```
String s = "9/10/11";
String[] foo = s.split("/");
```

JavaScript:

```
var s = "9/10/11";
var foo = s.split("/");
```

.NET:

```
string s = "9/10/11";
string foo = s.Split("/");
```

Python:

```
s = "9/10/11";
foo = s.split('/');
```

Some characters, like '\' which you're using as a delimeter have to be escaped, so they will be counted as a basic text character, not as an escape character. This means that your delimiter will be defined as "\\" for example in Java:

```
String foo = s.split("\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

if using java you can use split function java. that will itself provide you the array of elements split-ed on "/".

Comment: I am using javascript. So what i need to do sir?

Answer (score 0):

The backslash (`\`) is an escape character in Javascript.
See this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903661/2408648.

I suggest you to escape all backslashes then you can do:

```
var str = "9\\10\\16";
console.log(str.split("\\"));
```

Comment: How to escape all the backslashes? means how to convert op's string to  what you have written?

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "9\\10\\16" ;
  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"\\");
  String[] array = new String[st.countTokens()];
  for(int i=0;i<st.countTokens();i++)
  {
      array[i] = st.nextToken();
  }
```

Use `\\` in string variable to escape single `\` .

Comment: Sir can you tell me how to do this in javascript

Comment: use split method in javascript. see my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var str="09\\10\\11";
 var n=str.split("\\");
 alert(n);
</script>
```

for javascript

Comment: I would suggest you to not to post multiple answer. You can always improve your existing answer by edit that.