# writing JSON with "\\"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this string in json format

```
[{
    "EXTENSION" : ".pdf",
    "LINK" : "\\192.168.1.6\Varios\_SERV_IMG\ArchivosSocio\000000006000000006PSO000115-02-2016PDF.pdf"
}]
```

the problem is when ...

```
datos = $.parseJSON(res);
```

as I write \ in a string JSON?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your question or problem is. If you are getting an error, it would be helpful to share it. Other than that, the only suggestion I can make is to escape your JSON data values appropriately.

Comment: This question is related [JavaScript backslash (\) in variables is causing an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903488)

Comment: The JSON is invalid. You should let the JSON be generated for you, don't create it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The \ needs to be escaped to \\

so:

```js
[{
    "EXTENSION" : ".pdf",
    "LINK" : "\\\\192.168.1.6\\Varios\\_SERV_IMG\\ArchivosSocio\\000000006000000006PSO000115-02-2016PDF.pdf"
}]
```