# Javascript replace "\\" to "\"

Tags: javascript

How can I replace in my string `\\` to `\`? For example, I want to convert `RegExp('\\\\b')` to `RegExp('\\b')`. I've tried:

```
 mystring.replace('\\','\'');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript backslash (\‌) in variables is causing an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903488/javascript-backslash-in-variables-is-causing-an-error)

Comment: Its not duplicated, I just need to replace, is there anyway to it?

Comment: It's the duplicate. Read the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to replace all of the occurrences of two backslashes in a row into a single backslash, you use a regular expression with the `g` flag. Because backslashes are special in regular expressions, you have to escape them (with another backslash). You also have to use the return value of `replace`:

```js
var str = "Here: \\\\ and here \\\\";
console.log(str);
str = str.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: can't we replace with empty string

Comment: It just work when I have "\\\\" if I have just 2 slashes it didnt work /:

Comment: @TiagoCastro: If you have just two backslashes in a string literal, you have **one** backslash in the string, not two. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3903661/157247) on the question nicael pointed to.