# Why is this RegExp in String.replace removing my backslashes?

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

Let's say I have this string

```
"examples\output\$projectname$\$projectname$.csproj"
```

I want to replace all occurences of $projectname$ with some string. E.g. replacing it with TEST should yield:

```
"examples\output\TEST\TEST.csproj"
```

The closest I've come to achieving this is:

```
("examples\output\$projectname$\$projectname$.csproj")
    .replace(new RegExp("\\$projectname\\$", "g"), "TEST");
```

which yields:

```
"examplesoutputTESTTEST.csproj"
```

Even when writing...

```
("examples\output\$projectname$\$projectname$.csproj")
    .replace(new RegExp("output", "g"), "TEST");
```

...this will still remove the backslashes

```
"examplesTEST$projectname$$projectname$.csproj"
```

Why is this happening and how do I prevent this?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think you need to put an escape character (`/`) in front of your backslashes.

Comment: It's not the regex, it's just your initial string is wrong.  [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903488/javascript-backslash-in-variables-is-causing-an-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslashes aren't even there in the first place:

```js
// Prints "examplesoutput$projectname$$projectname$.csproj":
console.log("examples\output\$projectname$\$projectname$.csproj");
```

You need to escape the backslashes in your given string literal. A string literal `"\$"` will evaluate to `"$"`. But a string literal `"\\$"` will evaluate to `"\$"`:

```js
var path = "examples\\output\\$projectname$\\$projectname$.csproj".replace(new RegExp("\\$projectname\\$", "g"), "TEST");

console.log(path); // "examples\output\TEST\TEST.csproj"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My first solution (just as yours) does indeed work in code where the path is in a variable. I was just forgetting to escape the backslash in the string literal for my testing setup.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript (as with many other languages), the back-slashes in your literal string are acting as escape characters, preserving the character after them; the effect is that the slashes disappear.  This means that your string written as:

```
"examples\output\$projectname$\$projectname$.csproj"
```

is interpreted as,

```
"examplesoutput$projectname$$projectname$.csproj"
```

You would need to use the back-slash to escape the back-slash:

```
"examples\\output\\$projectname$\\$projectname$.csproj"
```

Note that if you have a string with single back-slashes in them (from an API which returns Windows file paths, for example), the back-slashes are already part of the string, so it does not need to be processed to escape the existing slashes.

Back to your original code, you needn't create a new `RegExp` object. Javascript supports regex-literals. So you can write:

```
"examples\\output\\$projectname$\\$projectname$.csproj"
.replace(/\$projectname\$/g, "TEST")
```