# How to Remove double backslashes in a string to Single one?

Tags: javascript

[image]
My string is `tel:\\99999999999`. How i can replace '\' to '\' single? I want output like: `tel:\99999999999`.

Please see attached image backslashes not showing into question.

Comment: `str.replace('\\\\','\\')` maybe?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen more like `str.replace('\\\\', '\\')`

Comment: More like: `tel = tel.replace(/\\+/g, '\\')`

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes no need for a regex here

Comment: How are you getting `tel` value? From an input?

Answer (score 3):

You should escape the slash twice:

```
"tel:\\99999999999".replace('\\\\', '\\');
```

Comment: I think you should write four slashes in the string: `"tel:\\\\99999999999"`

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Why?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes No it's not necessary, the string will be automatically escaped by the the JS engine.

Comment: Because if you paste `"tel:\\99999999999"` into the console, it just shows one slash, making your replace unnecessary

Comment: It would only make sense to have two slashes if `"tel:\\99999999999"` was an `<input>` value and you retrieve it like `input.value.replace(...`

Answer (score 0):

use `.replace()` to achieve what you want, `str.replace("\\\\","\\")`

```js
var str = "tel:\\99999999999";

console.log(str.replace("\\\\","\\"))
```

Comment: If you `console.log(tel)` before the replace it still works

Comment: This answer has already been posted, and why do you include jquery??

Comment: @Denny When I started to write the answer it was not posted, so that's why I made it, And the reason I included jquery is that it started with a jquery tag, so that's why. And if you look then I wrote the answer first in the comment, then I wanted to include it as an actual Answer. Please check the facts before

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `tel.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\")`.

**Demo:**

```js
var tel ="\\99999999999";

console.log(tel.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\"));
```

You need to escape the `\` character with another `\`, because it's an [**escape character**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in JavaScript, you can check [JavaScript backslash (\) in variables is causing an error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3903488/3669624) for further reading.

Answer (score -2):

You can do like this

```
"tel:\\99999999999".replace('\\\\', '');
```

Comment: Just do not down vote without running it. Open your browser console and copy paste that code and hit enter. You will know well.

Comment: @Denny Aka is right, it does give the right result as it should. You seem to comment on a a lot without checking the facts first.

Comment: Yes, @CarstenLøvboAndersen you are right. Such person should be blocked by stackoverflow.

Comment: @AKA I don't agree that he should be blocked, he should just think abit more before posting

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yeah, that is really true words from you.

Comment: @AKA Thanks, but in general I agree with him, he also jump to my answer and said that it been posted before, true, but I wrote the answer in the comment first and at that time there were no answers so I wanted to make one. when I posted the answer there were other answers then. So he's too fast.

Comment: Yes @CarstenLøvboAndersen we need to be pretty quick while adding answers as there are lot of them posting answers simultaneously. So eventually it ended up being duplicate answers.

Comment: @AKA any, i upvoted your answer to make the voting right again, Good day to you

Comment: My bad, had a bad day and wasn't thinking clearly, I apologize for my ignorance

Comment: Please remove the down vote and if possible make an up vote