# using regex in nodejs filtering multiple delimiters

Tags: node.js, regex

i have multiple emails in string with multiple delimiters `,;:/|\""`.

im trying to slip and add in array.

im almost there small issue is coming 
i know something wrong in my regex.

Node JS Code:

```
var x = "mmmm lll\"kkkk\jjj/iiii,hhhh:gggg+ffff-eee+dddd;cccc|bbbb:aaaa";

    var separators = [' ', '\\\+', '-',  ';', '"',  '\\|','//', '\\|',  '\\\(', '\\\)', '\\*', '/', ':', '\\\?'];
    console.log(separators.join('|'));
    var tokens = x.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'));
    console.log(tokens);
```

here is output:

```
|\+|-|;|"|\||//|\||\(|\)|\*|/|:|\?
[ 'mmmm@gmail.com',
  'lll@gmail.com',
```

**'kkkk@gmail.comjjj@gmail.com',**
  **'iiii@gmail.com,hhhh@gmail.com',**

```
'gggg@gmail.com',
  'ffff@gmail.com',
  'eee@gmail.com',
  'dddd@gmail.com',
  'cccc@gmail.com',
  'bbbb@gmail.com',
  'aaaa@gmail.com' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

[1] You can add a `,` to your list of separators.

[2] When you are declaring the string `x`, it assumes that it has to escapes what comes after the `\`, so if you display `x` you will see it without the `\` delimiter. So change the delimiter to `\\`.

[3] Add a delimiter for the `\` also.

New updated code working in nodejs:

```
var x = "mmmm lll\"kkkk\\jjj/iiii,hhhh:gggg+ffff-eee+dddd;cccc|bbbb:aaaa";
\\                     ^^^ <- Note this, otherwise it's trying to escape `j`
console.log(x)
var separators = [' ', '\\\+', '-',  ';', '"',  '\\|','//', '\\|',  '\\\(', '\\\)', '\\*', '/', ':', '\\\?', ',', '\\\\\+'];

console.log(separators.join('|'));
var tokens = x.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'));
console.log(tokens);
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.. i can not change string ("mmmm lll\"kkkk\\jjj/iiii,hhhh:gggg+ffff-eee+dddd;cccc|bbbb:aaaa)  this is not in my hand ... thats why i need to do something in regex code ...

Comment: The problem is that js doesn't consider \ to be in the string. See `x.indexOf('\\')`

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903661/4110233, you need \\ everywhere instead of a single one as it is a special character in js.