# Path separators are missing

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, cefsharp

I'm trying to implement the selection of a local file and send its path to js.

```
_mainWindow.Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(
  "document.getElementById('location').value=" + 
  '\'' + openFileDialog.FileName + '\'');
```

this option returns a path without delimiters - "PathTofile", although the path itself is written to the file - "Path\To\File". tell me, please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just English post, We can't understand your post !!!

Comment: @Aria Oh, sorry...   I need  execute script path to file with backslashes - "Path\To\File", but my script return me - "PathToFile", please, 
tell me what the problem is ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Елизавета so edit your question, you are getting more down vote unless you edit and translate it to English.

Comment: if you use \\ instead of \ ?

Comment: @Radu and \\ and \ - did not help

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `openFileDialog.FileName`? Also have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903488/javascript-backslash-in-variables-is-causing-an-error .

Comment: @mjwills D:\\Prog\\My\\File.exe

Comment: @mjwills https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/11/12/ed51a05d72fa5df7b273c4539dbae085-full.png

Comment: Yes, your value only has single slashes in it, not double. Use `_mainWindow.Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(
  "document.getElementById('location').value=" + 
  '\'' + openFileDialog.FileName.Replace(@"\", @"\\") + '\'');`

Comment: @mjwills Thank You ! Its this is the right decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `FileName` has single slashes in it. JS will interpret those slashes as [escape characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903661/34092).

The simplest solution is to replace your single slashes with double slashes:

```
_mainWindow.Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(
    "document.getElementById('location').value=" + '\''
        + openFileDialog.FileName.Replace(@"\", @"\\") + '\'');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_mainWindow.Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync( "document.getElementById('location').value=" + '\'' + openFileDialog.FileName.Replace(@"\", @"\\") + '\'');
```

Thank's you!

Comment: You are welcome. I'll add my original comment as an answer.