# JQuery remove backslash with some words in string

Tags: jquery

my string is "\upload\document\file.txt", i want to remove the "\upload" part in that string with jQuery. I try this one but it does not work:

```js
var filePath = "\upload\document\file.txt";
filePath = filePath.replace('\upload', '');
console.log(filePath);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript backslash (\‌) in variables is causing an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903488/javascript-backslash-in-variables-is-causing-an-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `\u` at the start of the string is being interpreted as Unicode. Hence the error you see in the console.

To avoid this problem you need to use `\\` to escape the single slashes in the string:

```js
var filePath = "\\upload\\document\\file.txt";
filePath = filePath.replace('\\upload', '');
console.log(filePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `\`

```js
  var filePath = "\\upload\\document\\file.txt";
  filePath= filePath.replace('\\upload', '');
      
  console.log(filePath)
```