# Copy to clipboard html with back slash

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a button that when clicked will copy a text to clipboard.

```
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('A\B\C\D')">Click here</button>
```

but when using this approach, the text copied to the clipboard is:

```
ABCD
```

instead of

```
A\B\C\D
```

Can someone help here please?

Comment: Double the slashes: `"A\\B"`. Also read on "backslash escape sequences"

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903661/6313073).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

`<button onclick="copyToClipboard('A\\B\\C\\D')">Click here</button>`

or

`<button onclick="copyToClipboard('A/B/C/D')">Click here</button>`

and see if any of the two will work for your task.

Answer (score 0):

\ is the JavaScript escape character.
To use a backslash use `\\`.

Further reading: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp