# Preserving double backlashes in a string "as is" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, string, backslash

I have an endpoint that returns back a string in a JSON, i.e.:

`"<p>Rationalize the denominator of each expression.  Write your answer in simplest form.</p><p><code class='latex inline'>\n\\displaystyle\n\\frac{\\sqrt{3}+\\sqrt{5}}{\\sqrt{2}}\n</code></p>"`

When I try to use that string in JavaScript, it automatically converts it to:

`"<p>Rationalize the denominator of each expression.  Write your answer in simplest form.</p><p><code class='latex inline'> \displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2}} </code></p>"`

The backslashes are gone as it reads it as an escape character instead of it being a part of the string. I need these backslashes to persist in the string, but I lose it before I can manipulate it in any way. What can I invoke to keep the string as it is originally?

Comment: Why do you need the backslashes?

Comment: JSON doubles the literal backslashes, parsing it converts them back to single backslashes. You shouldn't need to keep them.

Comment: The whole point of serialization formats like JSON is that the result is the same as the original data. Don't fight it.

Comment: I think following should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903488/javascript-backslash-in-variables-is-causing-an-error

Comment: @hev1 I'm using a library (katex) that requires the backslashes to exist in order to render the text.

Comment: `"<p>Rationalize the denominator of each expression.  Write your answer in simplest form.</p><p><code class='latex inline'>\n\\displaystyle\n\\frac{\\sqrt{3}+\\sqrt{5}}{\\sqrt{2}}\n</code></p>".replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");`

Comment: @averageUsername123 Does that help?

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic comment... but ... @Barmar Are you the same "barmar" I worked with at BBN who helped write portions of BIND 8?

Comment: @Dshiz I did work at BBN, although I wasn't involved in BIND 8 coding.

Comment: @Barmar myth precedes legends, then. We used to refer to hearing from you as being "barmared" when it came to DNS related topics. :)

Comment: @hev1 `error  Unnecessary semicolon  no-extra-semi`

Can you help explain what it is you're trying to do? A regex expression parameter to replace all "\" with "\\" ?

Comment: @averageUsername123 That looks like an eslint error which has nothing to do with hev1's code or the functionality of it. I guess you simply added an additional semicolon when you copy-pasted hev1's code.

Comment: @averageUsername123 Yes, it replaces all backslashes with two backslashes.