# Javascript how to verify if string contain ' \ ' with includes()

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

I'm trying to to verify if a string contain this simbol \.

```
if (this.inputCity.includes('\')){
    // do something,,,
}
```

The problem is that backslash? is an escape? character...
So how can I check if string contain \ ?

Thanks!

Comment: Escape it with a backslash.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript backslash (\‌) in variables is causing an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903488/javascript-backslash-in-variables-is-causing-an-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's an escape character, you have to escape it with another backslash. :)

```
if (this.inputCity.includes('\\')){
    // do something,,,
}
```

Comment: Thanks, there is a mode includes both of backslash?  ( / and \ )?

Comment: the forward slash '/' isn't a special character so you can search for that as normal. If you want both in the same statement, it would be: `if (this.inputCity.includes('\\') || this.inputCity.includes('/')) {///do something }`

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the escape character by just adding another one:

```js
if (this.inputCity.includes('\\')){
    // do something,,,
}
```

Comment: Thanks, there is a mode includes both of backslash?  ( / and \ )?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the AND operator:

```js
if(this.inputCity.includes('\\') && this.inputCity.includes('/') {
     // This will run if inputCity includes \ AND (hence the operator name) /
}
```

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65968020/edit) your previous answer and update the code with this.