# Can js file be compiled in a different folder from the source folder?

Tags: directory, esbuild

I'm building an [Obsidian plugin](https://github.com/obsidianmd/obsidian-sample-plugin), and it uses [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/) to bundle ts file to js file. The ts file is located at `D:\foo1\foo2\...`, and I want the js file to be at `D:\bar1\bar2\...`. The reason for this is because I want the source folder is in a different folder than the plugin folder, so that when syncing it to mobile I don't have to exclude the source files.

I was suggested to edit the esbuild.config.mjs file, and I find in the documentation that beside the [outfile](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#outfile) config there are also [outdir](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#outdir), [outbase](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#outbase). However, these are the results when I'm using them:

#### outdir

```js
outdir: 'D:\Quả Cầu\B Nội dung\Knowledge graphs\Cây vấn đề\.obsidian\plugins\dotmaker'
```

> error: Failed to create output directory: mkdir D:\GitHub\Obsidian\dotmaker\D:Quả CầuB Nội dungKnowledge graphsCây vấn đề.obsidianpluginsdotmaker: The directory name is invalid.

#### outbase

```js
outbase: 'D:\Quả Cầu\B Nội dung\Knowledge graphs\Cây vấn đề\.obsidian\plugins\dotmaker',
```

It prints the js content in the terminal, but the real file isn't changed.

It seems that I can only create the js file inside the source folder. Is that possible?

Comment: Because the examples probably used unix style path separators ( ie forward slashes `/`) and not windows style path separators (ie backslashes `\ ` ). A backslash in a javascript (and most other languages) string has a [special meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903488/javascript-backslash-in-variables-is-causing-an-error) so if you want your string to literally contain a backslash you have to escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't correctly format the content of the `outdir` setting. When using backslashes `\` as path separator on windows, you have to escape them. Ie use

```
outdir: 'D:\\Quả Cầu\\B Nội dung\\Knowledge graphs\\Cây vấn đề\\.obsidian\\plugins\\dotmaker'
```

Comment: when I do this with `outbase`, it prints the js content and not update the file. Why is that?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used esbuild myself so I can't help you with any specific configuation issues.