# How am I to ask if a backslash is equal to a backslash?

Tags: javascript

`'\'`

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

So how am I to ask if a backslash is equal to a backslash?

`if(string[5]=='\'){}`

or

`string.indexOf('\')`

Comment: The backslash is an escape character, so you need to escape the escape, to give: `(string[5] == '\\')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript backslash (\‌) in variables is causing an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903488/javascript-backslash-in-variables-is-causing-an-error)